# Calculating value from a group of cells with Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I am trying to read a csv file of horse track information.

I am attempting to code for the post positions (col 3) in race 1 the max value for the field qpts (col  210).  I have spend days on researching this and can find no clear answer on web or youtube.

When I run the code below, I get "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous....."

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',100)

df = pd.read_csv('track.csv', header=None, na_values=['.'])

index = list(range(0,200,1))
columns = list(range(0,1484,1))

if df.ix[2]== 1:
    qpts = (df.max([210]))
    print (qpts)
```

Comment: race # is col 2

Comment: Hello, please could you provide some rows (i.e. `df.head()`) as an example. Without an example is difficult to figure out the problem and what you want to do.

Comment: There is some kind of phenomenon with pandas novices that they somehow all tend to migrate towards using `.ix`. `.ix` should almost never be used as it can be ambiguous. `iloc` or `.loc` should always take precedence when possible. I wonder what the cause of this ix disease is....

Answer (score 0):

Here `df.ix[2]== 1` is going to return a Series. You need to use a function such as `.any()` or `.all()` to combine the Series into a single value which you can do a truth statement upon. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',100)

df = pd.read_csv('track.csv', header=None, na_values=['.'])

index = list(range(0,200,1))
columns = list(range(0,1484,1))

if (df.ix[2]== 1).any(axis=1):
    qpts = (df.max([210]))
    print (qpts)
```

In the case above we are checking to see if any of the Series elements are equal to 1. If so then the the `if` statement will be implemented. If we do not do this then we could have a situation as follows:

```
print(df)

Out[1]:

   1    3
   2    7
   3    1
   4    5
   5    6

print(df.ix[2]== 1)

Out[2]:

   1    False
   2    False
   3    True
   4    False
   5    False
```

Therefore the Series would be both simultaneously `True` and `False`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with

`if df.ix[2] == 1`.  The expression `df.ix[2] == 1` will return a `pd.Series` of truth values.  By putting an `if` in front, you are attempting to evaluate a series of values as either `True` or `False`, which is what is throwing the error.

There are several ways to produce a series where the value is `210` and the indices are those where `df.ix[2] == 1`

This is one way

```
pd.Series(210, df.index[df.ix[2] == 1])
```